What is the greatest number among these $11$ numbers?
The average of $11$ consecutive terms of the sequence $a_n = 3n + 7$ is 58. What is the greatest number among these $11$ numbers?
This is the answer:
$$-,-,-,-,-,58,-,-,-,-,73$$
$$58+5 \cdot 3=73.$$
I cannot understand the answer. Do you have any idea why this is the answer?
I can solve this problem from another way:
$$3n+7=58 \iff n=17.$$
For the greatest one, it is $n=22$, so the greatest number is $22 \cdot 3+7=73$.

This is hard to follow.  Which $11$ numbers?  Can I take any consecutive string from that progression?  I note that your first sentence just trails off...did you mean did give us the average of the $11$ numbers?

@lulu This is the average of 11 consecutive numbers

What is the average of $11$ consecutive numbers?  I think you meant to write that the average was $58$, but I am just reverse engineering the official solution.

Note that the average of any $11$ consecutive terms in that progression is equal to the $6^{th}$ term in that collection.  (Why?).  It follows that the final, and greatest, term in the collection is the average plus $15$.  But you need to provide the average.

@lulu, the average is 58. Because they are consecutive numbers, the average number is in the middle of the sequence.

Once again, nothing in the post says that the average is $58$.  I believe you intended to write that, but you did not.

@lulu Sorry the part "is 58" was removed from my question. I edited it.

Ok, so what's the question?  You agree that the average, $58$, must be the $6^{th}$ term of your progression.  But we have $58=a_{17}$ so the final one in your collection must be $a_{17+5}=a_{22}=73$.

$$-,\underbrace{-,-}_{+3},-,-,58,\overbrace{-,-,-,-,x}^\text{5 elements}$$
Since the sequence is $3n + 7$, the difference between 2 adjacent elements is +3.
Because you are interesting in 11 of them, there are 5 after the middle.
So the last element is +3, 5 times, after the middle one.

You have implicitly asserted that the median here is equal to the mean, which is true  when $a_n = 3n + 7$ but might not be true in other cases
